# Site column data not lost if site column is deleted: Is this safe?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-column

We have created a site column (from site settings page) of type: Image with formatting and constraints for publishing: Name --> Plans.

We then created a custom list --> add existing site column --> 'Plans'.

We have added 5 items (Title and Image) into this list. Now, we noticed that the images no longer are displayed in the view, we can see only the image URLs. I came across a solution that suggests to remove the site column (from site settings --> site columns). Then, re-create the a site column with same name. This it seems will fix the issue.

Now, I would like to know whether it is safe to delete a site column and yet be able to preserve the data (images) in the list. I have tried to replicate this and after deleting the site column, the data from list (image) are not lost. If we delete the list column then the list data column values do get deleted.

I have created this thread to confirm whether it is safe (no data is lost) to create, delete and create a site column.